# Magento 2 -> Error Checkout -> Notice: Undefined index: number in vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/AttributeMerger.php on line 174

Tags: magento2, attributes

> The problem appears when entering the checkout page

1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index:

> number in
> /var/www/../vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/AttributeMerger.php
> on line 174
>
> Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: number in
> /var/www/../vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/AttributeMerger.php
> on line 174

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail just putting an error is not sufficient otherwise it will be deleted from the community.

Answer (score 0):

There is only certain input validation you can put, check the allowed values.

```
/**
* Map input_validation and validation rule from js
*
* @var array
*/
 protected $inputValidationMap = [
     'alpha' => 'validate-alpha',
     'numeric' => 'validate-number',
     'alphanumeric' => 'validate-alphanum',
     'alphanum-with-spaces' => 'validate-alphanum-with-spaces',
     'url' => 'validate-url',
     'email' => 'email2',
     'length' => 'validate-length',
 ];
```

If you want to bypass the issue just add

```
'number' => 'validate-number'
```

In the above array in file :

> ../vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/AttributeMerger.php